# Does this array algorithm have a name?

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to match up two different types of users (males and females), maybe I'm going about this the wrong way but it's like this:

Users of type male: [A, B, C, D, E ...]
Users of type female: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...]

Both arrays will always be the same size.  I want to match the first type with the second type (each one has a unique identifier).  The output should be like below multidimensional array where the key is male and value is female:

The items are objects of users from a DB.

```
 1: [
  [A, 1], [B, 2], [C, 3], [D, 4], [E, 5]
 ]
 2: [
  [A, 2], [B, 3], [C, 4], [D, 5], [E, 1]
 ]
 3: [
  [A, 3], [B, 4], [C, 5], [D, 1], [E, 2]
 ]
 4: [
  [A, 4], [B, 5], [C, 1], [D, 2], [E, 3]
 ]
 5: [
  [A, 5], [B, 1], [C, 2], [D, 3], [E, 4]
 ]
```

If it helps, each of these users belong to the same DB table of users, one type are male and one type are female.  I intend on turning this into a request/response type method so that it returns a json object of the array matrix.  I do not need any help with APIs or anything like that, I just need help with the core algorithm.

If you do not wish to provide an answer, please can you provide the name of the formula so I can research it? Or pseudocode, and I'll write it up myself.  Many thanks.

### Edit

Here is an attempt but it's not giving the expected outcomes and it is taking almost 2 seconds :O https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfe00576cb77eb23d0e094cac5961689c85b2442

### Edit 2

I didn't realise it would be more complex than I thought, now I'm looking another output that would need to be valid (i.e. null values because sometimes we need to make it so that males or females don't have a match)

```
[
  0=> [
    "a"=> "k", "b"=> "l", "c"=> "m", "d"=> "n", "e"=> "o", "f"=> "p", "g"=> "q", "h"=> "r", "i"=> NULL, "j"=> NULL
  ]
  1=> [
    "a"=> "l","b"=> "m", "c"=> "n", "d"=> "o", "e"=> "p", "f"=> "q", "g"=> "r", "h"=> NULL, "i"=> NULL, "j"=> "k"
  ]
  ...etc...
]
```

In this new output example the assume the key is male and the value is female.  BUT it doesn't have to be, I'm merely just wanting a resultset I can use that has a male and a female match.

I have also tried as suggested: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fb0120c57a766bc383f64712c54557c3d1b00e7 but same problem again it is taking too long, it takes average 1.5 seconds.

If we turned it into an API, it would have a massive impact if all the requests kept taking a few seconds all the time perhaps more since over the internet.

Comment: array_combine ?

Comment: do all the combinations have to be broken down into groups?

Comment: No, I am looking for each iteration that follows the matrix output formula I posted above.  Like my attempt here https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfe00576cb77eb23d0e094cac5961689c85b2442 except this is taking too long with just 10 items, I predict we could have hundreds of users!

Comment: gotcha, there is a `crossJoin` method on Collection to get all permutations, you could order/group the result how you wanted

Comment: @lagbox yes into groups of however many users there are, i.e. the length of the array of the males or females (each array always being same size as each other from initial input).  HOWEVER, a male can be paired with a NULL value, or a female can be paired with a NULL value, but in each iteration each item would always be unique because sometimes we might not have a male or female available for the other gender ;)

Comment: @lagbox thanks I'll checkout the collection methods,  Note: I'm using latest Laravel 8 for our project.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton sorry - just messing about with this code trying to make it faster because it keeps taking on average 1 and half seconds even with just 10 items.  The current output looking at is but doesn't need to be :
`
[
  0=> [
    "a"=> "k", "b"=> "l", "c"=> "m", "d"=> "n", "e"=> "o", "f"=> "p", "g"=> "q", "h"=> "r", "i"=> NULL, "j"=> NULL
  ]
  1=> [
    "a"=> "l","b"=> "m", "c"=> "n", "d"=> "o", "e"=> "p", "f"=> "q", "g"=> "r", "h"=> NULL, "i"=> NULL, "j"=> "k"
  ]
  ...etc...
]`

Comment: @Sherry When I run my solution on my own webserver it runs in `0.0002` seconds (copied directly from your Sandbox code), and it meets all of your requirements. Time result: https://i.ibb.co/4KZSpCz/image.png - screenshot of code: https://i.ibb.co/3My93nR/image.png. There is absolutely no reason that this should take more than milliseconds to run, it's not very complex. The Sandbox does not appear to display the correct amount of time for some reason.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thank you very much, this satisfies the requirements listed so I'll go with this in our Laravel project.  Btw, if anyone happens to know if there is a name for this, I'd be really interested.  I thought it was some sort of in-place algorithm but not sure which.  It looks like a timetable to me and I see matching patterns, but all the examples input was 1 combined dataset and 1 combined output.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this solution should work for you.

```
<?php
    
    $array1 = [
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'
    ];
    
    $array2 = [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    ];
    
    //create array to hold final arrays
    $final = [];

    //loop through either array, this is to make sure there is an equal number of arrays in $final at the end
    foreach($array2 as $outer) {
        
        //create temporary array to be added to $final later
        $tmp = [];

        //loop through $array1 because the position doesn't change on each iteration
        foreach($array1 as $key => $male) {

            //get value of same key from array not being looped
            $female = $array2[$key];

            //add both values to tmp array
            $tmp[] = [$male, $female];
        }
        
        //this is the magic that moves the first key to the end after each iteration
        //array_shift removes the first element from array, and returns it
        //so we remove it from the beginning and add it back to the end
        $array2[] = array_shift($array2);

        //reset the keys of $array2 so they match $array1
        $array2 = array_values($array2);
        
        //add tmp array to $final, then move onto next iteration
        $final[] = $tmp;
        
    }
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => B
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => D
                    [1] => 4
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => E
                    [1] => 5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => B
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C
                    [1] => 4
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => D
                    [1] => 5
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => E
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => B
                    [1] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C
                    [1] => 5
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => D
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => E
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => B
                    [1] => 5
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => D
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => E
                    [1] => 3
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => B
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => D
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => E
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much.  I have updated the code here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fb0120c57a766bc383f64712c54557c3d1b00e7 and added some null values, will this be okay? The null values I need because sometimes we are going to make it so that some users do not have a match with anyone.  This would mean that the same user may potentially not have a match and multiple sessions (iterations of the array) but that is fine iwth us.

Comment: @Sherry Yes, it should still work. This solution is not dependent on the data being any certain type.